# Как сделать блок неактивным при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли сделать на JQuery функцию, которая при клике на нужный блок делает его активным, а все остальные другие неактивными? И при повторном нажатии на активный блок также убрать его активность.

С первой частью я разобрался, сделал функцию такого рода:

```
$(".block").click(function(){
$(".block").each(function(){ $(".block").removeClass("active"); });
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на активный блок он делался неактивным?

Я пробовал сделать кнопку, при нажатии на которую убирается класс "active", но может это реально сделать в пределах одной функции, не используя сторонних кнопок, дабы код был более лаконичным.

Comment: ну там добавьте что-нибудь по типу: если у блока есть класс `active` то одно действие, в другом случае - другое

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно вот такое:

```js
$('.list').on('click', '.item', function(){
  // Советую использовать проверку, что нажатый элемент не активный
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    // Если не активный, то выполняем следующее:
    // Находим именно активный элемент и снимаем с него класс "активности"
    $('.list') // берём родителя
      .find('.item.active') // ищем активный
      .removeClass('active'); // "отнимаем" класс
      
    // Далее нажатому элементу выдаём класс
    $(this) // берём текущий элемент
      .addClass('active'); // выдаём класс
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не стоит скрывать код, если он не очень большой и к тому же только один кодовый фрагмент в сообщении.

Comment: @0xdb, привычка скрывать, чисто чтобы другие ответы не перекрывать.

Comment: _чтобы другие ответы не перекрывать_ - ответы в одном сообщении? Если да, то это я и имел ввиду.

Comment: Не, я про "соседей". Если раскрыть код, то соседний ответ выйдет за приделы экрана.

Comment: Ах про соседей! Ну вы очень скромны, молодой человек ))

Answer (score 0):

Если активность блока у вас маркируется наличием класса `active`, тогда используйте примитивы:

- сделать активным `$().addClass("active")`
- сделать не активным `$().removeClass("active")`
- переключить активность `$().toggleClass("active")`

В целом, мне кажется, что можно просто по клику переключать класс активности:

```
$(".block").click(function(){
    // На нажатом элементе .block переключаем состояние активности
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    // Для всех элементов .block, кроме того, на который нажали, уберем активность
    $(".block").not(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

Не знаю, насколько это изящно, смотрите сами